# How to import a scrollable frame from one script into a frame in a different script tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for the confusing title basically what I'm trying to figure out how to import a frame from one script into another. I'm not sure how I would call it since it has so many functions. Here are my two scripts:

File Name - wrapper:

```
import tkinter as tk
import workingcatch
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()

outputframe = LabelFrame(master=root, width=800, height=700) #where i want to import the script 
outputframe.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10,pady=10)

root.geometry('1280x720')
root.mainloop()
```

File Name - workingcatch:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
import logging
import time
import sys

info = logging.getLogger(__name__).info
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s")

platform = windows = 'mswin'

# define dummy subprocess to generate some output
cmd = [sys.executable or "python", "-u", "-c", """
import itertools, time

for i in itertools.count():
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
exit()
""", "exit"]

class OStream(Thread):

    enable_print = True

    def handel_line(self, line):
        if platform == windows:
            # Windows uses: "\r\n" instead of "\n" for new lines.
            line = line.replace(b"\r\n", b"\n")
        if self.enable_print:
            info("got: %r", line)
        if self.stream_print is not None:
            self.stream_print(line)

    def stop(self):
        self.alive = False

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            for s in self.ostrams:
                line = s.stdout.readline()
                if line:
                    self.handel_line(line)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        info("OStream Exit")

    def pipe_proc(self, stream):
        self.ostrams.append(stream)

    def stream_callback(self, func):
        self.stream_print = func

    def __init__(self):
        self.ostrams = []
        self.alive = True
        self.stream_print = None
        Thread.__init__(self)

class Scrolable_Frame(tk.Frame):

    def get(self):
        return self.interior

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
            yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.interior = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor=tk.NW
        )

        def _configure_interior(_):
            size = (self.interior.winfo_reqwidth(), self.interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.config(width=self.interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(_):
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

        def _on_mousewheel(event):
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), 'units')
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

class ShowProcessOutputDemo(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        """Start subprocess, make GUI widgets."""
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('300x200+500+300')
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.stop)

        self.proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

        self.ostream = OStream()
        self.ostream.pipe_proc(self.proc)
        self.ostream.stream_callback(self.add_label)
        self.ostream.start()

        self.exit_button = tk.Button(
            self, text="Stop subprocess", command=self.stop
        )
        self.exit_button.pack(pady=20)

        self.scolable_frame = Scrolable_Frame(self)
        self.scolable_frame.pack(
            expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, pady=20, padx=20
        )

    def add_label(self, line):
        line_text = 'OStream line content: {0}'.format(line[:-1].decode())
        tk.Label(
            self.scolable_frame.get(), text=line_text
        ).pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, expand=True, fill=tk.X)

    def stop(self):
        """Stop subprocess and quit GUI."""

        self.ostream.stop()

        self.proc.kill()
        self.proc.stdout.close()
        self.proc.wait(timeout=2)

        info("GUI Exit")
        self.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ShowProcessOutputDemo()
    app.mainloop()
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the output from "workingcatch" into 'wrapper's frame.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Call it with `scroll = workingcatch.Scrolable_Frame()` or of you import with `from workingcatch import ScrolableFrame`

Comment: Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]. If the question is about importing a frame from one file into another, we don't need much more than the two files, the frame, and enough code to make it run.

Comment: If both the files are in the same folder, then you can import like how Alex has said

Comment: I'm still struggling to figure it out, would I replace the entire LabelFrame with the variable of scroll or would I call it somewhere in its properties?